# how to get the current year from postgres sql query

Tags: database, postgresql

how to get the current year from postgresql query, I tried like normal mysql query .But this is not working in postgresql?

```
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE());
```

Comment: `select extract(year from current_date), date_part('year', current_date);`

Answer (score 4):

try :

```
  select to_char(now(),'YYYY')
```

Answer (score 2):

you could also do this

```
select date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

In standard ANSI SQL (which is also supported by Postgres) this would be:

```
extract(year from current_date)
```